# How to print out php page properly?

Tags: php, html

I have index.php file with everything coded in pure PHP even HTML like this :

```
echo "<a href=\"index.php?formation:$p_id\" target=\"_blank\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-xs\"> $affname </button></a><br>";
```

If i want to simply print out the current web page it shows all href links and i would like to simply make it not show them. By the way the buttons don't show correctly too, it shows only borders with colors.

I got pointed out to use FPDF to convert my whole page into a PDF then print it out but i think there should be an easier way to fix this problem ?

Any explanation why it's doing that or how i can solve it would be great.
Thank you,

------UPDATE------
**Testing solution without button**

```
echo "<TD align=\"center\"><a href=\"$index.php?formation:$p_id\" class=\"noprint\">Formations</a></TD>";
```

The result is it's just empty, it even hide the word "Formations".

Comment: consider adding a stylesheet that targets printing so you can hide things you don't want to see when printing. http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Comment: The `button` element shouldn't be nested inside of an `a` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include all screen styles in the separate `@media screen {…}` rule;

Hide selectors

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

Usage:

```
<a href="#" class="hide">link</a>
```

Comment: I think this is almost working. I've just replaced .hide with .noprint . My question is updated with result from it.